# can't save JPG image with alpha

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
width, height = resized_image.size
dummyImg = np.zeros([height, width, 4], dtype=np.uint8)
for x in range(width):
    for y in range(height):
        color = seg_map[y,x]
        (r,g,b) = resized_image.getpixel((x,y))
        if color == 0:
            dummyImg[y,x] = [255,255,255,255]
        else:
            dummyImg[y,x] = [r,g,b,255]
img = Image.fromarray(dummyImg)
outputFilePath = '15d09a689ca0d4 Mod.jpg'
img.save(outputFilePath)
```

Hello, I am getting this error while trying to save image as "JPG", I included alpha channels in `dummyimg`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 620, in _save
    rawmode = RAWMODE[im.mode]
KeyError: 'RGBA'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/timmy/Desktop/image-background-removal-master/impr.py", line 79, in <module>
    img.save(outputFilePath)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2007, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py", line 622, in _save
    raise IOError("cannot write mode %s as JPEG" % im.mode)
OSError: cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG
```

I checked GitHub issue [cannot write mode RGBA as JPEG (4.2.0)](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2609) , they said it is solved and is now doable

Comment: In general, JPEG does not support alpha/transparency unless you use leading edge versions which most browsers and viewers will not understand. It's probably a poor idea. Try PNG, or TIFF if you have alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG file format cannot handle transparency. To save an image with color and transparency you need to use another format (e.g. PNG).

You can save to JPEG only if you drop the alpha channel and make all pixels opaque.

Comment: png works but doesn't jpg also allow (show) alpha ?

Comment: @madboy: no. JPEG is about images where transparency is not present. JPEG 2000 (file .jp2) addressed alpha/transparency but is not very popular.